# Out of the blue, linux mint makes the "unmount" and "mount" sounds

Tags: usb, mount, linux-mint, systemd

Not a big deal, except late at night when I forget to turn the volume down and it startles me... Once in a while, my linux mint makes the sounds it makes when unmounting and mounting a USB drive, consecutively, as if I unplugged and plugged a usb drive in. Why?

My LM18.3;

```
sbh@sbh ~ $ inxi -Fx
System:    Host: sbh Kernel: 4.13.0-31-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: Cinnamon 3.6.7 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3) Distro: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
Machine:   System: Apple (portable) product: MacBookPro11 3 v: 1.0
           Mobo: Apple model: Mac-2BD1B31983FE1663 v: MacBookPro11 3
           Bios: Apple v: MBP112.88Z.0142.B00.1708080655 date: 08/08/2017
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-4980HQ (-HT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 22349
           clock speeds: max: 4000 MHz 1: 2793 MHz 2: 2793 MHz 3: 2793 MHz 4: 2793 MHz 5: 2793 MHz 6: 2793 MHz
           7: 2793 MHz 8: 2793 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK107M [GeForce GT 750M Mac Edition] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 2880x1800@59.99hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GT 750M/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.111 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Card-2 NVIDIA GK107 HDMI Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.13.0-31-generic
Network:   Card: Broadcom BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter driver: wl bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: 24:a0:74:f2:c5:4a
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.6GB (20.4% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: APPLE_SSD_SM1024 size: 1000.6GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 202G used: 162G (85%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 26.21GB used: 23.82GB (91%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda7
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 63.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 0.0:62C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 336 Uptime: 4 days Memory: 10666.5/15949.3MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

I quickly checked the last files seemingly modified in `/var/log/` and they were; It happened around 21:47 to 21:48...

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm      622976 Feb 19 21:47 ufw.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm      135663 Feb 19 21:47 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm     2173452 Feb 19 21:47 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog            adm      101064 Feb 19 21:47 auth.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root      32388 Feb 19 21:48 Xorg.0.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root              root     234201 Feb 19 21:48 dpkg.log
```

I didn't know what to search for so I tried,

```
sbh@sbh /var/log $ sudo grep -E -rnw '/var/log/' -e 'Feb 19.*21:47|21:47.*Feb 19'
/var/log/syslog:1097:Feb 19 21:47:26 sbh kernel: [391857.805131] usb 2-4: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
/var/log/syslog:1098:Feb 19 21:47:32 sbh kernel: [391862.925412] usb 2-4: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
/var/log/syslog:1099:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.045638] usb 2-4: usb_reset_and_verify_device Failed to disable LTM
/var/log/syslog:1100:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.045638] .
/var/log/syslog:1101:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.045661] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Cannot set link state.
/var/log/syslog:1102:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.045719] usb usb2-port4: cannot disable (err = -32)
/var/log/syslog:1103:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.225537] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 10
/var/log/syslog:1104:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.589683] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
/var/log/syslog:1105:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.615549] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=8406
/var/log/syslog:1106:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.615557] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
/var/log/syslog:1107:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.615562] usb 2-4: Product: Card Reader
/var/log/syslog:1108:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.615566] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Apple
/var/log/syslog:1109:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.615570] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 000000000820
/var/log/syslog:1110:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.630863] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
/var/log/syslog:1111:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.631437] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
/var/log/syslog:1112:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.744877] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
/var/log/syslog:1113:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.744893] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
/var/log/syslog:1114:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.755219] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
/var/log/syslog:1115:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.755239] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
/var/log/syslog:1116:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 11: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4"
/var/log/syslog:1117:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 11 was not an MTP device
/var/log/syslog:1118:Feb 19 21:47:38 sbh kernel: [391869.647749] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     APPLE    SD Card Reader   3.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
/var/log/syslog:1119:Feb 19 21:47:38 sbh kernel: [391869.648653] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
/var/log/syslog:1120:Feb 19 21:47:38 sbh kernel: [391869.654623] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
/var/log/kern.log:11364:Feb 19 21:47:26 sbh kernel: [391857.805131] usb 2-4: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
/var/log/kern.log:11365:Feb 19 21:47:32 sbh kernel: [391862.925412] usb 2-4: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
/var/log/kern.log:11366:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.045638] usb 2-4: usb_reset_and_verify_device Failed to disable LTM
/var/log/kern.log:11367:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.045638] .
/var/log/kern.log:11368:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.045661] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Cannot set link state.
/var/log/kern.log:11369:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.045719] usb usb2-port4: cannot disable (err = -32)
/var/log/kern.log:11370:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.225537] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 10
/var/log/kern.log:11371:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.589683] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
/var/log/kern.log:11372:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.615549] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=8406
/var/log/kern.log:11373:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.615557] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
/var/log/kern.log:11374:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.615562] usb 2-4: Product: Card Reader
/var/log/kern.log:11375:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.615566] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Apple
/var/log/kern.log:11376:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.615570] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 000000000820
/var/log/kern.log:11377:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.630863] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
/var/log/kern.log:11378:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.631437] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
/var/log/kern.log:11379:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.744877] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
/var/log/kern.log:11380:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.744893] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
/var/log/kern.log:11381:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.755219] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
/var/log/kern.log:11382:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.755239] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
/var/log/kern.log:11383:Feb 19 21:47:38 sbh kernel: [391869.647749] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     APPLE    SD Card Reader   3.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
/var/log/kern.log:11384:Feb 19 21:47:38 sbh kernel: [391869.648653] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
/var/log/kern.log:11385:Feb 19 21:47:38 sbh kernel: [391869.654623] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
/var/log/ufw.log:2712:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.744877] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
/var/log/ufw.log:2713:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.744893] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
/var/log/ufw.log:2714:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.755219] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
/var/log/ufw.log:2715:Feb 19 21:47:37 sbh kernel: [391868.755239] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
/var/log/auth.log:794:Feb 19 21:47:56 sbh polkitd(authority=local): Operator of unix-session:c2 successfully authenticated as unix-user:sbh to gain ONE-SHOT authorization for action com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic for unix-process:27023:39186586 [/bin/sh -c pkexec /usr/sbin/synaptic --hide-main-window --non-interactive --parent-window-id 83886265 -o Synaptic::closeZvt=true --set-selections-file /tmp/tmppzubgw2g] (owned by unix-user:sbh)
/var/log/auth.log:795:Feb 19 21:47:56 sbh pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
/var/log/auth.log:796:Feb 19 21:47:56 sbh pkexec: pam_systemd(polkit-1:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
/var/log/auth.log:797:Feb 19 21:47:56 sbh pkexec: pam_ck_connector(polkit-1:session): cannot determine display-device
/var/log/auth.log:798:Feb 19 21:47:56 sbh pkexec[27024]: sbh: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/sbh] [COMMAND=/usr/sbin/synaptic --hide-main-window --non-interactive --parent-window-id 83886265 -o Synaptic::closeZvt=true --set-selections-file /tmp/tmppzubgw2g]
/var/log/auth.log:800:Feb 19 21:59:07 sbh sudo:      sbh : TTY=pts/7 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/grep -rnw . -e 21:47
/var/log/auth.log:803:Feb 19 22:03:08 sbh sudo:      sbh : TTY=pts/7 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/grep -E -rnw /var/log/ -e Feb 19.*21:47|21:47.*Feb 19
```

and,

```
sbh@sbh /var/log $ sudo grep -E -rnw '/var/log/' -e 'Feb 19.*21:48|21:48.*Feb 19'
/var/log/auth.log:806:Feb 19 22:05:30 sbh sudo:      sbh : TTY=pts/7 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/grep -E -rnw /var/log/ -e Feb 19.*21:48|21:48.*Feb 19
```

The kern.log mentions the USB disconnect and then finding an Apple one... also in syslog at 37 seconds in. And a `mtp-probe`? I see that `udevadm monitor` only works for this if it happened to be running. I wonder if this is when the 'mount' and 'unmount' sounds occur. But can someone explain to me what happened? and how to fix it?

My `udev` is version 229-4ubuntu4 and 229-4ubuntu21.1 - not sure why `apt-cache show udev` lists two... `journalctl` posts similar things but I can post it if it is helpful.

I have libmtp9 and libmtp-common if that helps...

TIA

---

*edit*

It again happened today, twice, so three times in two days; since I have been noticing it...

This OP has similar issues, but on a MBPretina, I'm not sure how it can relate to a MBP - I put Grub2 from dev8's debian in there (EFI) and it worked, and still does, successfully long before these sounds started happening. https://askubuntu.com/questions/332927/troubles-connecting-usb3-drive Also, I do have a process going on where there is a lot of writing to swap...

At no time was I ever plugging or unplugging a usb device (external). Also my partition formats are:

**gdisk:**

```
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)       Size  Code  Name    
     1              40          409639  200.0 MiB  EF00  EFI System Partition    
     2          409640       391759839  186.6 GiB  AF00  SSD   
     3       391759840       393029375  619.9 MiB  AB00  Recovery HD
     4       393029632       802629631  195.3 GiB  0700  BOOTCAMP    
     5       802629632      1048127487  117.1 GiB  AF00  Apple_HFS_Untitled_2    
     6      1048389632      1478469631  205.1 GiB  0700  Basic data partition   
     7      1478469632      1529669631   24.4 GiB  0700  Basic data partition      
     8      1529669632      1954207743  202.4 GiB  0700  Astra
```

maybe more helpful on file system type:

**blkid:**

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="51a8ec6c-2dbe-304d-ae7d-7529d82c0aed" TYPE="hfsplus"
/dev/sda3: UUID="6aac3d42-0f3f-3c04-95e5-8ab6b465df42" TYPE="hfsplus"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="BOOTCAMP" UUID="DA327232327213AB" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="047ec79c-1f4d-3c73-b1a2-f3ccb7a7205f" TYPE="hfsplus"
/dev/sda6: UUID="c403a9af-f7a4-4e3f-981b-33daf472b68f" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="5348c3ca-7f95-460c-b242-fa1445480d37" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="f49b3281-a94c-498f-a734-4debe70368a3" TYPE="ext4"
```

And I have `hfsprogs` installed, as well as `ntfs-3g`, but not `ntfs-3g-dev`

```
if any of this helps: 
dev2 contains The MacOS
dev2 contains mac osx stuff
dev3 contains mac osx stuff
dev4 contains windows 10
dev5 contains swap
dev6 contains LM18.3
dev8 contains debian
```

**Here is the latest one:**

**kern.log:**

```
Feb 20 07:59:44 sbh kernel: [428596.673690] usb 2-4: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Feb 20 07:59:49 sbh kernel: [428601.793902] usb 2-4: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428606.914169] usb 2-4: usb_reset_and_verify_device Failed to disable LTM
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428606.914169] .
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428606.914193] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Cannot set link state.
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428606.914256] usb usb2-port4: cannot disable (err = -32)
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.094090] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 14
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.378224] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.400017] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=8406
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.400023] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.400027] usb 2-4: Product: Card Reader
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.400030] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Apple
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.400032] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 000000000820
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.402669] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.402906] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.449028] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.449071] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.459427] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.459488] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:55 sbh kernel: [428608.420372] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     APPLE    SD Card Reader   3.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Feb 20 07:59:55 sbh kernel: [428608.421353] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Feb 20 07:59:55 sbh kernel: [428608.422926] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

**syslog:**

```
Feb 20 07:59:44 sbh kernel: [428596.673690] usb 2-4: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Feb 20 07:59:49 sbh kernel: [428601.793902] usb 2-4: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428606.914169] usb 2-4: usb_reset_and_verify_device Failed to disable LTM
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428606.914169] .
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428606.914193] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Cannot set link state.
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428606.914256] usb usb2-port4: cannot disable (err = -32)
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.094090] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 14
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.378224] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.400017] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=8406
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.400023] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.400027] usb 2-4: Product: Card Reader
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.400030] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Apple
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.400032] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: 000000000820
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.402669] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.402906] scsi host1: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.449028] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.449071] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 15: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-4"
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 15 was not an MTP device
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.459427] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.459488] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:55 sbh kernel: [428608.420372] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     APPLE    SD Card Reader   3.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Feb 20 07:59:55 sbh kernel: [428608.421353] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Feb 20 07:59:55 sbh kernel: [428608.422926] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

**ufw.log:** (My firewall is on - set to deny incoming and allow outgoing)

```
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.449028] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.449071] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.459427] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=144422 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
Feb 20 07:59:54 sbh kernel: [428607.459488] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:dcaa:37a0:7722:c1e8 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=782999 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24
```

**This** https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233144 seems to suggest timing issues and remains unsolved - I think he tried a different kernel... I could update I guess some minor revision - from 4.13.0-31.35 to 4.13.0-32.35... Still seems that there is something related to a "buggy" xhci_hcd driver but the possibility of a "better" one with ehci_hcd won't preserve backward compatibility - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=186617 I'll try the newer kernel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms you describe tells that your particular link "partners", your mass storage super-speed "removable disk", and USB 3.x host port, are having problems with LPM, link power management.

The link power management in USB 3.x framework includes U0 (normal active state), and three levels (U1, U2, and U3) of idle states with different levels of exit latency. The LPM is a local feature of a particular link, and, once enabled/configured by software, the entry-exit into the states are managed at hardware level, except for U3, which can be forced by host port (and is equivalent to the older USB SUSPEND state).

From the logs it is apparent that the device has failed to respond to LPM control commands. Not sure about Linux, but Microsoft has the following articles about LPM, [**Link power management in USB 3.0 hardware**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/link-power-management-in-usb-3-0-hardware), and follow the links, this one in particular [**about U1/U2 problems**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/common-hardware-problems-with-u1-or-u2-implementation). The keywords from MS papers should help you to locate corresponding Linux articles, if any exist.

The LPM has a fairly complicated exit protocol, with necessity of link re-training on every exit, and historically was plagued with hardware (and software/configuration) bugs, so in the first 3-4 years of adoption of USB 3.x standard this set of features was simply disabled in most USB devices.

Comment: Its really great you pointed me in the right direction, and thanks for the links too!! Yet more things to learn.... Btw, it sounds like this is over my head for a solution... :(

Comment: @nate, yep, things are likely even more complicated. Your computer has C220 chipset, which is 5 years old. These early USB 3.0 implementations had quite a few "anomalies", which did require some preferential treatment at driver level, likely hand delivered to Apple. If you use Linux, these patches are unlikely. Best would be to find a way to entirely disable the LPM at host level.

Comment: Just trying to connect the dots for others coming across this:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/802712/how-to-disable-usb3-lpm-hardware-controlled-power-management is similar - it is a question about disabling LPM.

Comment: @nate, as your link shows, nearly two years, and still no answer... Problem with software stack is that the power management is the backbone of everything else in USB framework, so there must be deep changes in the code to disable the main function. The industry "solution" was to disable LPM on device side, so it will always reject host offers as LGO_U1/U2. The USB device must have some back door to cheat this way.